# Why is geom_density plotting my data differently from the expected image?

Tags: r, ggplot2, simulation, density-plot

I have the following task statement:

In this task we want to simulate random variables with density

[image]

To do this, write a function r_density(n) that simulates n of such random variables.
Then use this function to simulate N = 1000  of such random variables. Using geom_density() you can now estimate the density from the simulated random variables. We can compare this estimate with the real density. To do this, create a graph that looks like this:

[image: Expected Plot]

Problem is, however, that I don't understand why my output looks like this:

[image: My Plot]

Why is the raked density plotted in such a weird way? Can someone explain to me why it looks like that and how to get the estimated density from the expected image?

This is the corresponding code I wrote for the above plot:

```
library(tidyverse)

N <- 1000

r_density <- function(n){
  exp(-abs(n))/2
}

x <- runif(N)

tb <- tibble(
  x = x,
  density_fkt = r_density(x)
)

ggplot() +
  geom_density(
    data = tb,
    mapping = aes(
      x = density_fkt,
      y = ..scaled..
    )
  ) +
  geom_function(
    fun = r_density,
    xlim = c(-6,6),
    color = "red",
    size = 1
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(
  x = "x",
  y = "Dichtefunktion f(x)",
  title = "Geschätzte (schwarz) vs echte (rot) Dichte"
  )
```

Comment: In the example, the x values go from -6 to 6. In your code, `x <- runif(N)`, and the default for `runif()` is between 0 and 1. But evaluating a function at random points is not the same as simulating a random variable.

Comment: Are you trying to perform [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling)? If so, I think you skipped the "inverse" part. There's nothing wrong with your plotting code. You just didn't generate the data as intended. If this is for an assignment, you should probably ask your instructor for some guidance.

Comment: Okay now I understand where the problem was, namely that I have not yet written the r_density function correctly. But how can I now simulate the random variables with the given density? What does simulate mean here in this sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use inverse transform sampling or rejection sampling. I choose rejection sampling.

```
library(tidyverse)

N <- 1000

r_density <- function(n){
  exp(-abs(n))/2
}

x = c()
while (length(x) < N) {
  y = rnorm(1)
  while (y > 6 | y < -6) {
    y = rnorm(1)
  }
  u = runif(1)
  if (u < r_density(y)/(dnorm(y) * 3)) {
    x=append(x, y)
  }
}


tb <- tibble(
  x = x,
  density_fkt = r_density(x)
)

ggplot() +
  geom_density(
    data = tb,
    mapping = aes(
      x = x,
      y = ..density..
    )
  ) +
  geom_function(
    fun = r_density,
    xlim = c(-6,6),
    color = "red",
    size = 1
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(
    x = "x",
    y = "Dichtefunktion f(x)",
    title = "Geschätzte (schwarz) vs echte (rot) Dichte"
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's the inverse transform sampling method (this involves some difficult integration, so perhaps not what your teacher intended)

```r
r_density <- function(n) {

  cdf <- function(x) {
      1/4 * exp(-x) * (-1 + 2 * exp(x) + exp(2*x) - (-1 + exp(x))^2 * sign(x))
  }

  sapply(runif(n), function(i) {
  uniroot(function(x) cdf(x) - i, c(-30, 20))$root
  })
}
```

Plotting gives:

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(r_density(1000))) +
  geom_function(
    fun = function(x) exp(-abs(x))/2,
    xlim = c(-6,6),
    color = "red",
    size = 1
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(
    x = "x",
    y = "Dichtefunktion f(x)",
    title = "Geschätzte (schwarz) vs echte (rot) Dichte"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for coding the alternate :)